# Displaying font in the desired font-face in email .sent from localhost in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am having a rails app, in which I want to send the email,and apply the fonts on some text.And those font files are on my server.

I tried these setting in my application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

And then font face code in style tag in HTML template of email.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'TestFont';
src: url('<%= root_url%>assets/test-webfont.eot');
src: url('<%= root_url%>assets/test-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('<%= root_url%>assets/test-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('<%= root_url%>assets/test-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('<%= root_url%>assets/test-webfont.svg#MelbourneRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

But these fonts file has no effect on the email sent.
I also tried to put the font files in public/fonts folder but no success.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: Custom fonts work in almost no email clients: http://css-tricks.com/custom-fonts-in-emails/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I also checked this http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-upload-or-use-my-own-custom-fonts/.
So will use the Image instead of Fonts.

Comment: Your approach does work but there is a really narrow support for this from the email clients. See: http://css-tricks.com/custom-fonts-in-emails/.